# How can I store FireBase Cloud Messaging tokens in firebase database in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a chat application and using FCM services.

When the user signs up on the app I am able to get the token by

```
 String token1;       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.w("TTTTTTTTTTTT", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                                                return;
                                            }

                                            // Get new FCM registration token
                                            token1 = task.getResult();  //this is the token

                                            // Log 
                                            Log.d("TTTTTTTTTTTT", token1);

                                        }
                                    });
```

Now, after getting the token I want to store it in Firebase Database along with the associated user.

So the **User** would have **a email, a password , a city and a token**.

```
signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String em = email.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                final String na = name.getText().toString();
                final String ci = city.getText().toString();
                if (em.equals("") || pass.equals("") || na.equals("") || ci.equals("")) {
                    name.setError("Enter your name");
                    password.setError("Enter your password");
                    city.setError("Enter your city");
                    email.setError("Enter your email");
                    Toast.makeText(ActivitySignup.this, "Please fill all the Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);




FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").
child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).
setValue(new UserModel(em, na, ci,token1 ));  //Creating a new user and storing name ,email, city and token in database


startActivity(new Intent(ActivitySignup.this, YearChooseActivity.class).putExtra("activity_name", "ActivitySignUp")
.putExtra("timesVisited", timesVisited));

                                Toast.makeText(ActivitySignup.this, "Successfully Register User \n" + em, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                Toast.makeText(ActivitySignup.this, Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(new UserModel(email, name, city , token1 ));  //Creating a new user and storing name ,email,`

The problem is that the token does not gets stored in Firebase. When I pass a random String as the token parameter lets say I pass " Kobe will be remembered" as the argument

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(new UserModel(email, name, city ," Kobe will be remembered" ));  //Creating a new user and storing name ,email,`

Then it gets stored in the database pretty well.

When I sign up with a test user let's say **name=a , email = a@gmail.com , city = a** then in the realtime database the **token** is not saved. This is how the realtime database looks.

```
"aBnS2fuXo2gmvcxzqy3z3mgFpiv2" : {
      "city" : "a",
      "email" : "a@gmail.com",
      "name" : "a"
    }
```

But when I hardcode the **token** value to a random string lets say "Arnold" by using  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(new UserModel(email, name, city ,"Arnold" ));`

then the database looks like

```
"aBnS2fuXo2gmvcxzqy3z3mgFpiv2" : {
      "city" : "a",
      "email" : "a@gmail.com",
      "name" : "a"
      "userToken" : "Arnold",

    }
```

For notification I need the token for the opposing party, hence **how do I store the token of all users in firebase along with their other credentials ?**

Comment: Where in your code are you using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(new UserModel(email, name, token1 ));`?

Comment: I have updated the post and added whatever I was trying, your attention would be appreciated.

Comment: I still not see where in your code ae you using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("USERS").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(new UserModel(email, name, token1 ));`.

Comment: Edited the formatting, now it might be clearly visible to ya

Answer (score 0):

you definitely don't store them in the same location it's not good security practice. also, the user may sign out or change their phones you don't want to send the notifications to the old device.

save the FCM token under the user information or a subcollection.
then if you want to message them using that token you just use their UID to get their token and send them a message. You can securely do that using cloud functions.

Comment: How do I "save the FCM token under the user information"  please be more informative . I've tried storing the token in sharedPreferences (just for a try) but it do not get stored. Again how do I save the token in firebase realtime database ?

Comment: 1- it has nothing to do with sharedPreferences, you need to save this information on your DB. 2- you need to request the FCM locally and get the FCM Token 3- add this token where you saved you user information in the DB